# How to mock a function to fail twice but succeed a second time?

Tags: typescript, sinon

I am testing a function that makes an API call. I would like to mock the API request to fail twice and succeed a third time. How can I use sinon mock to do that?

Comment: why? what is the user story you're trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider wrapping the function in a closure.

```
type BooleanClosure = (...args: any[]) => boolean;

const testFunction = (): boolean => {
  return true; // simulate correct response
};

const makeFailingThenSucceedingTest = (
  numberOfFails: number,
  callback: Function
): BooleanClosure => {
  let attempts: number = 0;
  return (...args) => {
    if (++attempts > numberOfFails) return callback(...args); 
    return false; // simulate fail
  };
};

const simulateAttempt = makeFailingThenSucceedingTest(2, testFunction);

console.log(simulateAttempt()); // false
console.log(simulateAttempt()); //false
console.log(simulateAttempt()); // true
```

You could expand this functionality to determine the response on failure, response on success, have it work with promises, etc.